# Java Property Binding

Tags: java, data-binding

I'm looking for a class set that could provide me binding to visual components.

I have for example a lot of textboxes, and pojos that I receive from ORM layer, now I just want to bind the pojo's properties to this text fields.

I found the Presentation Model pattern, but it seems usefull just in case you have a plain Pojo. But I have something like:

```
Person
 + Name
 + Telephones[]
   + Number
   + Comment
 + Age
```

For name and age, PM is just perfect. But for telephones, when I change something on one object that is stored on that collection, Person needs to be notified, in order to trigger its onChange events.

Is there a framework or class set that provides me this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jGoodies bindings library is still my goto solution for this: [jGoodies libraries](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries/)